# Javascript Uncaught Type Error on Live environment only, works fine on Dev

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a baffling problem.  A small bit of javascript used to count upto a given number set up within a Wordpress childtheme and adapted from the parent theme.  The script works perfectly in my development environment, but in the live environment using the exact same codebase, the code fails and returns the familiar

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems to work fine on the first run but fails on subsequent runs.  The particular line of code that is failing on the live server is this:

```
$(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
```

I have checked and double checked the codebase (it's identical) and checked permissions of all files (all readable).  I'm utterly baffled - can anyone shed some light on this?

You can see it here http://bit.ly/1vUX8pf

In the example, it is the top counter that is failing.  The code was adapted slightly from the counter the counter at the bottom which continues to work fine.   To say I'm baffled would be an understatement!

Full code here:

```
(function($) {

function audioSecondsInit() {
    $('.nectar-audioseconds').each(function() {
        if($(this).has('[data-symbol]')) {
            if($(this).attr('data-symbol-pos') == 'before') {
                $(this).find('.number').prepend($(this).attr('data-symbol'));
            } else {
                $(this).find('.number').append($(this).attr('data-symbol'));
            }
        }
    });

    if(!$('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
        $('.nectar-audioseconds').each(function() {
            // FAILS HERE >>>
            $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
                var $endNum = parseInt($(this).find('.number span').text());
                $endNum = $endNum + (23671233 * Math.floor(( (new Date()) - Date.parse('12/01/2014') ) / 86400000));
                $(this).find('.number span').countToFormat({
                    from: 0,
                    to: $endNum,
                    speed: 1500,
                    refreshInterval: 30
                });
            }, { offset: '105%', triggerOnce: true });
        }); 
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){ 
    audioSecondsInit();
},100); 

$.fn.countToFormat = function (options) {
    console.log("countToFormat");
    options = options || {};

    return $(this).each(function () {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
            from:            $(this).data('from'),
            to:              $(this).data('to'),
            speed:           $(this).data('speed'),
            refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
            decimals:        $(this).data('decimals')
        }, options);

        var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
            increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

        var self = this,
            $self = $(this),
            loopCount = 0,
            value = settings.from,
            data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

        $self.data('countTo', data);

        if (data.interval) {
            clearInterval(data.interval);
        }
        data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

        render(value);

        function updateTimer() {
            value += increment;
            loopCount++;

            render(value);

            if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
            }

            if (loopCount >= loops) {
                // remove the interval
                $self.removeData('countTo');
                clearInterval(data.interval);
                value = settings.to;

                if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
                    settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
                }
            }
        }
        function render(value) {
            var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
            $self.html(numberWithCommas(formattedValue));
        }
        function numberWithCommas(x) {
           return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: My guess is that the module that's supposed to define the `waypoint` function isn't included.

Comment: That's not a standard javascript function, right?  In which case it should be defined within the javascript used within the Wordpress theme?  It *should* all be there if so, but I'll doublecheck.  But that wouldn't account for the js working the first time?

Answer (score 1):

In your site I don't see the `waypoint.min.js`.

Home, I debugged it and saw that it is failling at the first processing of the function because `.waypoint` does not exist.

Comment: Do you mean waypoints.min.js?  That is here: /wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js

Comment: Sorry but I can't see it.. Are you sure you can?

Comment: Ok but are you sure this file is set in the page you gave? Because I can't see it and the error seems to confirm that observation.

Comment: In the page link there are two counters - they both use the waypoint function - presumably the bottom one working shows this is available?  The top counter seems to works the first time but not the second time.  I'm totally baffled.

Comment: Try to include that line in your page just to see: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.audioanalytic.com/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's really strange like you said.. it's like the script was removed of the page by another script. Is it possible in your page?

Comment: Added the script into the header and it didn't fix things.  I'm inclined to think it's an environment issue, as it runs once OK on live and then fails, but runs perfectly locally every time.  I think I'll need to push it onto the sysadmin - thanks for your input on this

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry for not having been able to help more than that!